# C++/CX and C++/CLI dependency

Tags: c++-cli, c++-cx

What is the relationship between C++/CX and C++/CLI from the syntaxes and compiling process view?
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162168/what-are-c-cx-and-c-cli-and-how-do-they-relate-to-c-and-winrt is not so comprehensive. Does anyone have more info?

Comment: It isn't that helpful to think they have *anything* in common.  The syntax looks a lot alike because they both solve the same problem, interfacing to a foreign type system.

Answer (score 5):

(This answer represents my own personal experience as a tester involved in the implementation of C++/CX, and should not be construed as bearing the opinions of anyone else.)

Internally, when Windows announced that they were building the Windows Runtime, and it was decided by The Powers That Be that one of DevDiv's primary goals was to support this API and provide useful projections into the various languages, a small design team was formed to look at the unique challenges and opportunities presented by this for the C++ team.  I became one of the compiler testers assigned to this feature, which at the time we called "MoCOM" (Modern COM).  For context, it is important to point out, I was not on the language design team, but I was privy to some of the early drafts of the design.

It was unclear what form this eventual language would take on, and there were a number of different proposals (some of which were lower-level than others).  One thing became clear: the goal in the end was to fully leverage the new Windows Runtime, while developing something that would be compatible with C++, and would, behind the scenes, be performant and wholly native.  There was also very little time to develop this new language.

The designers of WinRT had also taken a hard look at what it would mean for their runtime to be used by different languages, and had considered strongly how .NET languages (C# in particular) would interoperate with their runtime.  This meant that a lot of WinRT concepts mapped fairly neatly onto existing .NET concepts.  (The two runtimes were attempting to solve many of the same problems and provide a similar feature set, so this is not entirely surprising.)

In the end, what this meant is that the existing syntax of C++/CLI matched the concepts of WinRT fairly closely, and had already solved many of the more philosophical challenges of how to represent all of these same concepts in a way that was compatible (to varying degrees) with C++ syntax.  It also had the advantage of being already implemented in the compiler with a large bank of existing tests.  Finally, the intellisense team was at that time hard at work implementing C++/CLI intellisense, so we could get C++/CX intellisense for small additional outlay (at least compared with a brand-new syntax).

However, though the syntax was the same, the actual code-generation was drastically different. In .NET, the runtime does a lot of the heavy lifting for you; the language defines the types and the MSIL for the expressions, but the runtime does a lot of heavy lifting: type layout, native code generation, garbage collection, etc.

A couple examples:

- In the native C++/CX world, the ^ was conceptually and syntactically like the C++/CLI ^ (it represents a pointer to an interface or class), but was in **implementation** quite different.  Where in C++/CLI, you merely told the runtime it was a managed pointer of a certain type (a * in MSIL) and the runtime "did magic," in C++/CX, a ^ was a smart pointer, where the compiler needed to insert AddRefs and Releases at appropriate times (e.g. when it went out of scope).
- "gcnew" in C++/CLI became a simple, single line of MSIL. "ref new" in C++/CX would need to determine the appropriate factory, create an instance of the factory, and then ask the factory to create an instance of the underlying class.
- In C++/CLI, you would simply make a function call on a class pointer, in C++/CX if you had a class pointer, you had to determine the appropriate interface the requested function was actually on, QI for that interface, and then call the function against the result of the QI.

These differences were numerous and each concept mapping presented unique challenges. Additionally, my examples are all about *consuming* WinRT types; having the compiler able to also *author* types compatible with WinRT was a whole other can of worms.

All this to say: while the syntax of C++/CLI and C++/CX are very similar, under the covers the implementation is entirely different.  This was a lot of work, but it was also a deliberate choice on the part of the design team to develop a language which was compatible with the concepts of WinRT but did not take a dependency on the .NET runtime (since it was unnecessary and there were theoretical performance advantages).

If you'd like to learn more about what's actually going on under the covers, Deon Brewis, one of the designers and the main developer of the language extension, gave an excellent in-depth talk on the guts of the implementation at Build 2011: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-690C.  (I'm the guy behind the keyboard.)